# openMP different versions features table

Tags: openmp

I searched through web, however I was not able to find any feature table w.r.t different openMP versions?
There is a [table](http://www.openmp.org/resources/openmp-compilers/) showing support of different compilers w.r.t different openMP versions. However, I am interested to see a kind of detailed version. (seeing which features are supported in different compilers)

Comment: Even if you would define what you want from your table, I doubt whether any ready-made version is available.  For example, "full support of OpenMP 4.5" in current gcc in some cases means that the directives are accepted but ignored.  Another question of possible interest is whether the OpenMP directives over-ride compiler settings (as they do for Intel /fp:source or /Qvec- but do not for gcc).  If you want a listing of gradual feature introduction in past Intel compilers, you will wish in vain.

Answer (score 3):

This is a moving target, so it's hard to keep the http://www.openmp.org/resources/openmp-compilers/ table up to date. But the table does link to the documentation associated with each compiler, so that's your best bet. 
You can join the OpenMP Forum (http://openmp.org/forum) to ask specific questions about implementations.

--(webmaster@openmp.org)